# how to insert 190k records in one single INSERT statement?

Tags: mysql, insert, insert-statement

Inserting about 190k records having 4 column in it..but its taking too long..  waiting for localhost.. for long time.. any solution on this?....

```
I tried

SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=524288000;
```

for current session..

Comment: The objective is simply to construct 190,000 rows as efficiently as possible?

Comment: I'd be tempted to start over, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Try to remove all indexes (except the primary) and recreate them after the insert - indexes are good for SELECT but very bad for INSERT.